# Struts2 no encuentra index

Tags: struts2

Buenas a todos, estoy haciendo un proyecto pequeño con la nueva versión Struts 2.5.13 y siguiendo la guía [oficial](https://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-23-to-25-migration.html) no consigo que arranque.(Error 404, no encuentra recurso).

**ACTION** Un action lo mas simple posible:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class InitAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{


   @Override
   public String execute()
   {
      String resultado="success";       
      System.out.println("Holaaa resul("+resultado+")");

      return resultado;
   }
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

<package name="default" extends="struts-default">        
    <action name="init" class="com.mncars.commons.actions.InitAction">
        <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

**Web.xml**

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>   

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

**Index.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.net.URLDecoder"%>
<%
   HttpSession ses = request.getSession();
   response.sendRedirect("init");
%>
Bienvenido a la pagina!
```

Las librerías que uso son:

```
commons-fileupload-1.3.3.jar
commons-lang3-3.6.jar
freemarker-2.3.23.jar
javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
log4j-api-2.8.2.jar
mybatis-3.2.2.jar
ognl-3.1.15.jar
struts2-core-2.5.13.jar
```

**Proyecto:**

[image: Estructura proyecto]

**URL Probada**

http://localhost:8080/FacturaModerno/init

Comment: Te falta lo básico en la pregunta: ¿Qué URL has probado?

Comment: @PabloLozano Tienes razon, ya esta puesta.

Comment: init dirige a index que a su vez redirige a init? puedes tener un bucle ahí, aunque no creo que sea la causa de tu error

Comment: @PabloLozano pues si era por eso, aunque esto lo he simplificado de un problema mayor y hay algo que no hago. Aun asi gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Asegúrate de que tu `<context-root>` esté definido. En JBoss y Tomcat el nombre de tu archivo war se convierte en el "context root", ejemplo: FacturaModerno.war -> `/FacturaModerno`. Otra forma de definirlo es usando el `application deployment descriptor` o archivo `application.xml`

```
<application...>
    <display-name>Factura Moderno</display-name>
    <module id="FacturaModerno">
        <web>
            <web-uri>FacturaModerno.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/FacturaModerno</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
...
```

Utiliza el url `http://localhost:8080/FacturaModerno/` para accesar el `index.jsp`